# Delete query mysql - need clarification

Tags: mysql, database-performance, delete-row

```
delete from tablename where id in ('val1','val2',....,'val6000');
```

'id' is a FK column [char(50)]

IN query clause contains 6000 values

after 12 min 10 seconds, 1270000 rows are deleted from table 'tablename'.

tablename contains 2 indexed cols apart from a PK and a FK ('id' is FK col).

My doubt is, what takes more time, Is it the time to delete 1270000 rows? or parsing of that where clause to determine the rows to be deleted?

And is there a way to reduce this execution time?

Comment: What happens if you run a separate query for each id?

Comment: Parsing the query will be small. 12 minutes for deleting nearly 1.3 million rows in a table that contains a few indexes seems a very decent number.

Comment: @Pekka: I didnt try running the query separately for each id. Think thats not a better way.

Comment: @e4c5: But the same query runs only around two minutes in MS SQL with same amount of data present

Comment: `Think thats not a better way` well, try it out. It might be.

Comment: I also think what @Pekka웃 mentioned is right. Your IN clause might be taking time.

Comment: Did you try with disable keys, delete, enable keys? Is your MS server and mysql on similar hardware?

Comment: @e4c5: yes. MSSQL and MySQL are in similar hardware. And my table is innodb type. Think not possible to disable and enable keys. I may drop and create indexes. But that itself will take more time.

Comment: Hi @Pekka웃 i tried that delete query in batches, means instead of 6000 values in 'in' query, tried with 1000 values, 6 times, but it took 42 minutes. so single query is best it seems. but i am trying to reduce from 9 minutes to at least 3 to 4 mins.

Comment: hmm. Can you turn `id` into an `int`?

Comment: Not possible Pekka..!

Comment: Did you commit after each batch? In example 6000 rows commit, 6000 rows commit, etc.

Comment: Hi @dcieslak, i ran that query in Query browser itself, not in code. I ran in query browser to determine the exact amount of time taken.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see indexes, PRIMARY KEY, engine, datatypes, etc.

Comment: Don't use `CHAR` for variable length columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the configuration of your MySQL Server for 
innodb_buffer_pool_size

Change it some bigger value in case it's small - like 2 GB and try again.

Maybe you have issues to fit your data in the current buffer_pool.